# How to pass parameters for lambda Expression for Generic method to check duplicates in MVC EF 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, model-view-controller, lambda

I have more then 10 setup screens in my application. In each of them I have to check duplicates data.
For instance here is one sample code.

```
         private void CheckDuplication(AIRLINE airline)
        {
            var AIRLINE = context.AIRLINEs.Where(f => f.ABBREVATION == airline.ABBREVATION).FirstOrDefault();
            if (AIRLINE == null)
            {
                context.AIRLINEs.Add(airline);
            }
            else
            {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ABBREVATION", "Abbreviation already exists.");
            }
        }
```

Almost same code is used through out the project for each setup.
I want to make this method generic so that I can just call it any where I need to check Duplicates.
To do so, I have to pass parameters to the generic function that will set "Lambda Expression".
I have made a static class to access it from any where in my application.
The Question is how to pass parameters to such class (containing generic method) that will set lambda expression generically for different Tables and Columns and Show generic Error Message..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide preferable example of usage?

Comment: @JesseJames Sorry I didn't get you, This method is called when POST-METHOD of AIRLINE-CREATE is on run. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by example?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework already provides a mechanism to check if an entity exists in the database, by the [`AddOrUpdate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217945%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). You could use this in a method like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
...

public static string AddWhenNew<T>(DbContext context,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> identifierExpression, T item) where T : class
{
    var error = string.Empty;
    context.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(identifierExpression, item);
    if (context.Entry(item).State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
    {
        error = string.Format("{0} '{1}' already exists",
                              item.GetType().Name,
                              identifierExpression.Compile()(item));
    }
    return error;
}
```

in some static utility class.

Usage:

```
var error = Util.AddWhenNew(context, a => a.ABBREVATION, airline);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
{
```

etc.

I deliberately check `State != EntityState.Added` because the entity's state could be `Attached` or `Modified` here (modified when it's got the same `ABBREVATION` but another property differs). In reality though, when the entity is not `Added`, its state is incorrectly reported as `Detached` because of a [bug](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128) in `AddOrUpdate`.

So you have to make sure to only call `SaveChanges` when the object is added, and then dispose the context, otherwise you may inadvertently save other modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach (see the code below)

```
public void TestCase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = new AIRLINE(){ 
            Name = "111"
        };
        if(IsExists<AIRLINE>(entity, en => en.Name == entity.Name))
            throw new Exception("Already exists");
    }

    public class AIRLINE {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    DbContext context = new DbContext(null);

    public bool IsExists<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition) where TEntity : class {
        DbSet<TEntity> dataSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        if(!dataSet.Any(condition)) {
            dataSet.Add(entity);
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: First, it's nothing worse, than name method `IsExists`, when it must be named something like `AddWhenNotExists` (because it not only tests for existence, but also adds an item). Second, what is the benefits of your code, comparing to OP's?

Comment: First of all this code shows approach, this is not a sample that is ready to 'copy, paste and publish'. Second - this code will be written only one time, to check entity you need to write 1 row instead of new method.

Comment: OP can't throw exception (he uses MVC and wants to add validation error). The only thing your code allows to avoid, is a duplication of single `if` statement. IMHO, it's better to wait, when OP will update the question with usage samples.

Comment: Dennis, could you provide a better sample (that will have differences not only in method naming and in way to show error)? Now I'm really interested to see how it should be done (I have not worked with EF since last summer).

Comment: I can't, since use cases are not known. To many variations: e.g., if the number of criteria is limited (search by name or analogous property), all OP's code could be wrapped into a single method.

Comment: Thank you Both of you for your efforts. @Dennis Pleas let me know what do you mean by use cases?

Comment: @AffanShahab: the code (or pseudo-code), which shows, how do you plan to use the generic method you want to write; how many search criteria do you have (e.g., by id, by name), etc.

Comment: @Dennis As in code (shown in question) I have searched with ABBREVIATION. For all others, it may be Name or ID as well (Not more then these). Or any two of them.