# Which is better for database seeding: Add or AddOrUpdate?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I don't understand why it is recommended everywhere to use AddOrUpdate in the Seed method?

We develop application for half a year already and the AddOrUpdates overwrites user changes every time we update the server. E.g. if we call in the Seed:

```
context.Styles.AddOrUpdate(new Style { Id = 1,  Color = "red"  });
```

And user changes the Style to "green" then on next server update we overwrite it to "red" again and we get very annoyed user.

It looks that if we change AddOrUpdate to Add we will be guaranteed from overwriting user data. If we still need some special case we can put it to separate migration. Unlike the general Configuration.Seed method particular migrations don't run twice over the same database version.

Comment: Seem like you just need to sit down with a database and EF, and figure out how to do your migrations properly so that no loss of data occurs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, That's what I'm trying to do, without success so far. Added explanation.

Comment: Please do not alter title of the question in such a way that it changes its meaning. I've searched web for many days about this problem. There is a lot of various info. But exactly this piece of information is missing. I'm not interested in other stuff which I can find myself.

Comment: It's not recommended everywhere: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Comment: @Colin, thank you for the link. It helped me to feel not so lonely as before J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `Style`'s primary key is `Id`. [The overload of `AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176991%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) that you use only checks if there is a record having `Id == 1`. If so, it updates it. That's all.

What's going wrong here is that the primary key is a *surrogate key*, i.e. it's there for querying convenience, but it's got no business meaning. Usually, with migrations you want to look for the *natural keys* of entities though. That's how the user identifies data. S/he wants a green style, not a style identified by `1`.

So I think you should use [this overload of `AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217945%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```
context.Styles.AddOrUpdate( s => s.Color,
                            new Style { Id = 1,  Color = "red"  });
```

Now when there is no red style anymore, a new one is inserted, overriding the `Id` value (assuming that it's generated by the database).

From your later comments I understand that you want to Add data when they're new, but not update them when they exist (compared by primary key). For this you could use a slightly adapted version of an `AddWhenNew` method I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658075/861716). For your case I would do it like so:

```
public T void MarkAsAddedWhenNew<T>(this DbContext context, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> identifierExpression, T item) 
    where T : class
{
    context.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(identifierExpression, item);
    if (context.Entry(item).State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
    {
        var identifierFunction = identifierExpression.Compile();
        item = context.Set<T>()
               .Local
               .Single(x => identifierFunction(item)
                            .Equals(identifierFunction(x)));
        context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    return item;
}
```

Re-fetching the item from the local collection is a nuisance, but necessary because of a [bug](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128) in `AddOrUpdate()`. This bug also caused the error you got when setting the state of the original entry to `Unchanged`: it was a different instance than the attached one.

Comment: I don't think that the primary key is wrong here. The Style object can be connected to User object, the User to Friends, etc. All they are connected by ids. Yes, in perfect world we should have used natural keys, but in fact usage of primary keys is the best practical approach.
And I don't need to have the red style inserted if it is missing.

Comment: I'm sorry. The title of the question was changed by Robert. I don't know why. I've reverted the title of the question to the initial value.

Comment: I've tried to use your AddWhenNew approach but unfortunately it throws exception. Please see the commented code in my answer.

Comment: Changing the state to `Unchanged` is like attaching the entity twice.

Comment: OK, but is there any other way to revert the local entry changes without reverting the whole context?

Comment: I think this is what you want.

Comment: Great! Slight optimization added :)

Answer (score 0):

The way Add method acts is misleading. It Inserts data into database even if there is already a row with the same PrimaryKey as we do Add. It just creates new PrimaryKey ignoring our value silently. I should have tried it before asking the question, but anyway, I think I'm not the only one who confused by this. So, in my situation Add is even worse than AddOrUpdate.

The only solution I've come to is following:

```
    public static void AddWhenNew<T>(this DbContext ctx, T item) where T : Entity
    {
        var old = ctx.Set<T>().Find(item.Id);
        if (old == null) 
            ctx.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(item);

        /* Unfortunately this approach throws exception when I try to set state to Unchanged.
        Something like:"The entity already exists in the context"
        ctx.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(item);
        if (ctx.Entry(item).State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)            
            ctx.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;              
        */
    }
```